# Open graph: custom actions

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

I created a custom action and object.
The only problem I have is when publishing to FB, clicking on the icon or on the title redirect the user to a blank page instead of my application.

Where can I set the redirect link?
The only url I see is the one in the opengrap html but this one is suppose to be the adress of the og wright? (

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/) might help.

Basically, when the opengraph action is executed by your app, it sets the url that represents the object (which provides all the metadata for the object) and is also the URL that a user is sent to when they click the action in facebook.

E.g. https://graph.facebook.com/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook
         ?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

In this case, the cook action is being called, with a recipe object with the given OBJECT_URL. At that url, a page should exists (generated by you), with all the facebook metadata in the head tag so that the object can be correctly created, but also with actual web page data for the user to view.

Another link worth looking at for a working example is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#publish)